# WPF binding ComboBox to values from two objects

Tags: c#, wpf

Good afternoon,

I have an issue binding two objects to my combobox.

Technically, I'm trying to achieve this:

```
CrudGrid.SelectionChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    CustomersComboBox.SelectedItem = SelectedModel?.Customer;
};
```

But including all the cool features of TwoWay binding, meaning that changing SelectedItem in ComboBox also changes it on the SelectedModel.

To achieve such thing, I've tried doing this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CustomersComboBox" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="FullName" 
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedModel.Customer, Mode=TwoWay}", 
    SelectedValuePath="FullName"/>
```

Which didn't work nor display any error in the output console.

It's also worth pointing out that Customers is an observable collection of type 'Customer' whereas SelectedModel is of type 'Contract'.
Contracts have Customer attached to them via Contract.Customer.

I could easily provide this functionality with code behind but that kinda dodges the purpose of MVVM.

Comment: Could you please specify what do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Does it not set the SelectedModel.Customer to the customer you select from the combobox? Does it throw any runtime exceptions?

Comment: @mobearette it shows no errors in the Error List nor Output - the selected item just stays blank until I manually select something.

Comment: Try binding against `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`. Note that you use `SelectedValuePath="FullName"`, which means that `SelectedValue` would work with string values (i am assuming FullName is a string property) and not with `Customer` objects.

Comment: @elgonzo I've also tried binding SelectedItem aswell as creating an 'adapter' - a simple property called SelectedCustomer that returns in getter => SelectedModel.Customer' - no avail.

Comment: If you use SelectedItem, make sure to not use SelectedValueSelectedValuePath. Make sure that the binding can actually find the SelectedCustomer property (it should probably be in the same viewmodel as the `Customers` collection property). Make sure NotifyPropertyChanged event is raised whenever the value represented by SelectedCustomer changes. Set breakpoints on the setter and getter of the SelectedCustomer property to verify that the binding mechanism is actually being able to access the property.

Comment: @JCode: Does the Customer class have a Contract property?

Comment: @elgonzo Yes, it has multiple Contracts stored in ICollection under 'Contracts' property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to RaisePropertyChanged?

RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedModel.Customer); to notify the UI that something has been changed in the model. Perhaps implement it upon the selection change. That way it will fire up the property bound to your view.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
  if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

then

```
CrudGrid.SelectionChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    CustomersComboBox.SelectedItem = SelectedModel?.Customer;
    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedModel.Customer));

};
```